# Is it possible to clone a private GitHub repo using passport Oauth2 creds?

Tags: node.js, git, github, passport.js

I'm building an application that analyzes github repositories' code at the behest of users. To do that, I need to clone down their repositories locally.

As far as I can tell, all the directions out there are directed at cloning repositories using a manually generated auth token, rather than the accessToken that's automatically generated from a passport OAuth login. Here's GitHub's directions on the matter:

https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth

They link directly to their OAuth login docs, but experimentally it only works with manually generated keys.

How can I allow users to login with passport.js and then clone down their repositories?